# How to redirect to my site after express checkout paypal success without get value?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

How to redirect to my site after express checkout paypal success without get value ?

Normally when success payments express checkout paypal , paypal will redirect buyer to

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?token=xx-1111111111111111&PayerID=5555555555555
```

But i want to set paypal resirect to

```
http://www.example.com/page.php
```

How can i do ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Without the token you cannot complete the express checkout (by calling the DoEC API).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by storing that data in a session and bouncing to the page without that. This would be transparent to the user

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['token'], $_GET['PayerID'])) {
     $_SESSION['token'] = $_GET['token'];
     $_SESSION['PayerID'] = $_GET['PayerID'];
     header("Location: /page.php");
     exit;
}
```